# How can I select a random value from this array using JavaScript for discord bot?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

How can I select a random value from this array using JavaScript for discord bot?

```
var a = [ "lekh","lol"];

bot.on('message', msg=> {
    if(msg.content == "kilka" ){
        msg.reply( Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length ));
    } 
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change:
`msg.reply( Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length ));` to
`msg.reply(a[Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length)]);` to actually select the item from the `a` array